# How to enable mail() function

Tags: php, email

I am trying to work with a shared host in which the `mail()` function was disabled (I can see that on disabled functions on `phpinfo()`) by someone that I don't know.

All I have access is the root folder for the site files in the ftp, so I can't edited the php.ini in `/etc/` neither restart Apache (I know is a linux based OS).

Is there any way I can enable it by a secondary php.ini or `ini_set()`?

EDIT: I am aware of PHPMailer. I was trying to use it but it was being block as well. That's why I started trying to use `mail()`. Just to see if it would work

Comment: No. If you need to use the `mail()` function you need to find a new host. So your best option is to send mail using a third party system.

Comment: @JohnConde is right... you really shouldn't use mail() in PHP any way.. it is super unsafe if you don't know what you're doing... third party is probably the best route.

Comment: also.. your host will just reverse what you did or get really aggravated with you. Not worth the hassle.

Comment: Take a look at PHPMailer, it can send mail trough SMTP, which is much better then using the PHP mail function. Make sure to set the correct headers and make sure the "From" address is the same as the email address which you use to login with.

Comment: @Scriptman already tried phpmailer. It is being blocked also. That's why I tried using mail()

Comment: @CaioFavero Did you tried with SMTP?

Comment: @Scriptman Yes. Tried with PHPMailer as SMTP before trying with `mail()`. Both blocked

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a new host or upgrade to some different plan.

However you can go ahead with mailgun(https://www.mailgun.com/) which is very cheap and no cost to set up.

You just need to link your credit card for a safety but they never charge you unless you pass 10,000 emails per month(https://www.mailgun.com/pricing).

There are other solutions as well like mandrill or sendgrid. However, Mailgun is almost free unless you are using more transactions emails.

You can find the official mailgun php package in here : https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php

You need to check if curl is installed in your server though.

Secondly, trying to send emails directly is not a good practice. Most of the times they will end up getting in spam folder. Use SMTP and use PHPMailer Extention.

Steps to do so :

```
 1. So to cpanel and go to emails
 2. Create a new email account and add a password
 3. Click on configure mail client related to the new email address you have created
 4. You will get 2 tabs, SSL configurations and NON SSL configurations
 5. You can choose TLS, copy the outgoing host, email and password.
 6. Now install phpmailer and enter the above credentials and try sending email.
 7. Also as a safety, go to authentication in your cpanel and check if any issues are mentioned for emails just for safety.
```